# sed command from cmake does not change input file

Tags: sed, cmake

I want to modify `src/some_file.txt` before building my executable:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(MyProject)

add_custom_target(run ALL
    COMMAND sed -i "s@MY_PATH=\\(.*\\)@MY_PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/\\1@" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/some_file.txt
)

add_executable(e main.cpp)
add_dependencies(e run)
```

src/some_file.txt has content:

```
MY_PATH=something
```

Targets `run` and `e` get build but `src/some_file.txt` remains unchanged. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you're not using GNU sed or the file doesn't match the pattern.

My guess would be that you need to escape the backslashes again, but you don't need them anyway, just use:

```
sed -i 's@MY_PATH=@MY_PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/@'
```

Or simply

```
sed -i 's@MY_PATH=@&${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/@'
```

where `&` expands to the matched pattern. You should use single-quotes not double-quotes unless you specifically want the shell to expand variables.

Comment: I do not know how to do it with your second suggestion, but the first method works.

Comment: What do you mean you "don't know how to do it"? You write what I showed, and it works. `&` expands to the matched pattern, which in this case is `MY_PATH=`, so the second command is equivalent to the first.